# Open a menu with a List when I click in a view

Tags: android, menu

I'd like to show a menu when I click in a view (Linear/RelativeLayout) like the images below

Anybody knows how to do it?

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI-Element you're looking for is called a `Spinner` ([Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)). As far as I know the default implementation of the Spinner/Dropdown-List displays only text without any kind of drawable (circle) like in your screenshot.
So what you have to do is to create you own layout and `Adapter` for the Spinner.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh thanks, I think it's enough for me! Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The view you are looking for is called `Spinner`. Android has excellent [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) about this subject.

If you want the spinner to go up, like in your picture, you will have to place it at the bottom of your view, since it will only go up if there is no room below

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Spinner view](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

If you would like to customize the view elements, than you should change the default ArrayAdapter to yours and override the `getView()` method.